# ActiveRecord - Possible to pluck columns from a specific row? (Also, strange issues with select and quotation marks)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

I am trying to get a number of columns from a specific row via ActiveRecord like so (all examples are simplified for clarity):

`User.pluck(:id, :name, :date_joined, :field_containing_json)`

Previously, I was using a select statement which for some reason didn't work unless each column was enclosed in quotation marks:

`User.find(id).select("id, name, date_joined, field_containing_json")` fails for some reason and throws a `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR` while `User.find(id).select("id", "name", "date_joined", "field_containing_json")` works.

Thus this is a somewhat two-pronged question:

1. Why would one need to encapsulate each column name in quotation marks when using `select`?
2. Is there a way to `pluck` a specific row? `User.find(id).pluck(:id, :name ...)` throws `NoMethodError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the first version, you are passing one argument, the string `"id, name, date_joined_field_containing_json"`.  It's not that your second version is " encapsulating column names in quotation marks" -- it's that your second version is passing multiple arguments to the ruby Arel `select` method, which is the right way to call it. Multiple arguments, one for each column.  Your first one is passing one argument to `select`, a single string that includes spaces and columns. That's not what the select method wants.
2. Yes, there is a way to pluck from a specific row, like so:

   ```
   User.where(:id => id).pluck(:id, :name)
   ```

   You can use whatever other more complex conditions in the `where` you might want also, and then pluck certain columns.

   I tested this in Rails 4.1; I think pluck has been changing a bit lately, so it's possible it doesn't work the same in older Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see, I was just confused because the ActiveRecord documentation describes requesting multiple fields as one argument: [Selecting Specific Fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)

Comment: Hmm, either there's a bug in the AR docs, or I'm wrong and one argument to #select should normally work. I think I might be wrong, actually, so I don't really know the answer to your first question -- it would require looking at exactly what SQL is being sent to PG, and why PG doesn't like it.  But for what you're doing, I think .where.pluck is a better solution anyway; select is for when you really need to send custom SQL for something more unusual.